# Where does the redirect url fit in "Login with facebook" button for ios and android sdk's?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I come from a Backend background. I'm trying to gain more knowledge about Oauth2.0. I came across Login with Facebook using iOs and Android SDKs. There seems to be conflicting information.

On one hand, Oauth 2.0 Authorization code grant includes a redirect url (or callback) step, and that redirect url should be the one that exchanges the Authorization code to an actual access token on the server side.

On the other hand, those Facebook SDKs seem to do everything in client side and are able to get the access token without any redirect url.

Am I missing something? It doesn't seem to me like those SDK's follow the actual Oauth2.0 since the redirect url is not included in the guide.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Hi! Did my answer solve your question? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

They are using redirect url inside SDK, it's redirecting to the app(iOS/Android) itself using url scheme.

For iOS(android is quite the same):

You're enabling ability to accept this redirect using `CFBundleURLSchemes`, then when redirect is opened, `application:openURL:options:` gets called and you pass the url to the facebook sdk.